# Show: $\chi_{A_n}\overset{a.e} {\rightarrow}0\Leftrightarrow \mu (\cap _{n=1 }^{\propto }\cup _{k=n}^{\propto} A_k)\rightarrow$0

Tags: analysis

> Let  $(\Omega ,\mathbf{A},\mu )$ be a measure space :
> and $A_1,....,A_n...\in \mathbf{A}$
> Show: $\chi_{A_n}\overset{a.e} {\rightarrow}0\Leftrightarrow  \mu (\cap _{n=1 }^{\propto }\cup _{k=n}^{\propto} A_k)\rightarrow$0

What I did so far:\

$\Rightarrow $ Let us assume that $\chi_{A_n}\overset{a.e} {\rightarrow}0$, this means $\exists N \in \mathbf{A}:\mu (N)=0:\forall x \in \Omega \setminus N:\chi_{A_n}\overset{a.e} {\rightarrow}0$
let us take $A_k = \left \{ x|(_A(_k)) >\frac{1}{k}  \right \}$with $\mu (A_k)\leq \frac{1}{2^{k}}$
take N=$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }\bigcup_{\infty }^{k=n}A_k$
Then $\mu(N)\leq \mu (\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty }A_k)\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty }\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}}= 0$
Then we have $\mu (N)=0$ like in the definition of a.e and $\mu (\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty }A_k)$
So we also have $\mu (\cap _{n=1 }^{\propto }\cup _{k=n}^{\propto} A_k)\rightarrow$0

Is this correct until now ?
And i'm strugling to move on with "$\Leftarrow $"
Could maybe someone help me ?

Comment: It is not everything very clear e.g.  $\rightarrow$ for = and similar

Comment: Can be useful the following characterization: $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ if and only if $x\in A_k$ for infinitely many $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows by the identity
$$\{x\in \Omega | \chi_{A_n}(x)\not\rightarrow 0\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$$

For the $"\implies"$ we can do as follows:
since $\chi_{A_n}\rightarrow 0$ a.e. there exists $N\subseteq \Omega$ of measure zero such that $\forall x \not\in N$ we have $\chi_{A_n}(x)\rightarrow 0$. Since characteristic function takes values 0 and 1, we get that exists $N_x$ natural number such that for all $m>N_x$ $x\not\in A_m$ so $x$ belong to a finite number of sets $A_k$, by the previous comment (we have the following characterization: $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ if and only if $x\in A_k$ for infinitely many $k$.) we have proved the following implication
$$x\not\in N \implies x\not\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$$
it follows that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq N$ hence it has measure zero.

For the $"\impliedby"$ let's suppose $\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k)=0$.
Consider the set $N:=\{x\in \Omega | \chi_{A_n}(x)\not\rightarrow 0\}$.
By a similar argument as before we get $N\subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$. Which finishes the proof, by monotonicity of the measure.